# отфильтровать таблицу sqlite

Tags: mysql, sql, sqlite

Добрый день
Прошу помочь найти ошибку. Есть следующая задача, дано три таблицы с однотипными данными: table1, table2, table3, у каждой из них есть всего одна колонка name. table1 это общая таблица в ней записаны все имена сотрудников, в table2 и table3 есть лишь некоторые имена из таблицы table1. Мне надо построить sql запрос чтоб в результате получить лишь те имена которых нет ни в table2 ни в table3.
Пытаюсь сделать так, но не работает как надо:

```
SELECT table1.name FROM table1 WHERE table1.name
NOT IN
(SELECT table2.name FROM table2 UNION SELECT table3.name FROM table3)
```

Благодарю!

Comment: что значит "не работает так как надо" ? Сам запрос выглядит верным

Comment: Из контекста не понятно, что это за таблицы и почему именно так вы решили хранить сотрудников. [Нормализацию](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Нормальная_форма) не делали? И видимо нужно тег `sqlite` на `sql` исправить)

Comment: @AlexanderBragin, судя по заголовку, скорее надо исправить: `mysql` --> `sql`

Comment: Вы можете оставить только один тег: `mysql` или `sqlite`? ли вас интересует решение, которое будет работать в обеих БД?

Comment: @MaxU по ходу, да)

Comment: @Mike да, запрос верный, была грамматическая ошибка в данных, из-за чего и возникли недоразумения

Comment: @MaxU решение подойдет как для mysql так и для sqlite, Ваш вариант первый и рабочий, отмечаю его

Comment: всем огромное спасибо!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно воспользоваться оператором [EXCEPT](https://www.techonthenet.com/sqlite/except.php):

Пример:

**t1**

```
sqlite> select * from t1;
name
----------
name1
name2
name3
name4
name5
```

**t2**

```
sqlite> select * from t2;
name
----------
name1
name3
```

**t3**

```
sqlite> select * from t3;
name
----------
name5
name1
```

**Запрос:**

```
sqlite> select name from t1
   ...> except
   ...> select name from t2
   ...> except
   ...> select name from t3;
name
----------
name2
name4
```

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте так :

```
SELECT table1.name FROM table1 WHERE table1.name
NOT IN
(SELECT table2.name FROM table2) AND table1.name
NOT IN (SELECT table3.name FROM table3)
```

Answer (score 0):

Ну попробуйте ещё так:

```
SELECT table1.name 
FROM table1 
LEFT JOIN table2 ON table1.name=table2.name
LEFT JOIN table3 ON table1.name=table3.name
WHERE table2.name IS NULL
  AND table3.name IS NULL
```

Хорошо, если name в каждой из таблиц индексировано. Совсем хорошо, если оно ещё и уникально.